# Button that links to another page (specific part)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a button which directs me to a specific part on another page.

I have this code on my index page

```
<a href="BruinBier" class="btn">Bekijken</a>
```

If I press the button above it should redirect me to my webshop page under the part "Bruin bier" is it possible in pure HTML/CSS?

```
    <div id="BruinBier" >
        <h1>bruin bier</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can link to an element with an id-attribute by using a # followed by the id:

```
<a href="#BruinBier" class="btn">Bekijken</a>
```

or

```
<a href="/shop.html#BruinBier" class="btn">Bekijken</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use

```html
<a href="#BruinBier" class="btn">Bekijken</a>
```

Comment: Hello Dommilosz, i tried to do it like this; <div id="#BruinBier" > <h1>bruin bier</h1> </div> and <div class="box"> <h3>Bruine bieren</h3> <p>Deze bieren varieëren van donker amber tot diep bruin. De biersoort heeft een vrij lage bitterheid en smaakt vaak zoet</p> <a href="webshop.html#BruinBier" class="btn">Bekijken</a> </div> But I don't get to the part I need it to be.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple as you just have to specify a name or id to that part of the main web page, and then you can link it with other web pages by just putting both values (name of the page along with that part of its body) in "href" attribute.

For example-

```
<a href="page.html#anchor">text</a>
```

Here page.html is the name of webpage and #anchor is the name or id of that specified part.

Comment: Hello ChaudHary, i tried to do it  like this;

<div id="#BruinBier" >
            <h1>bruin bier</h1>
        </div>

and 

 <div class="box">
                <h3>Bruine bieren</h3>
                <p>Deze bieren varieëren van donker amber tot diep bruin. De biersoort heeft een vrij lage bitterheid en
                    smaakt vaak zoet</p>
                <a href="webshop.html#BruinBier" class="btn">Bekijken</a>
            </div>

But I don't get to the part I need it to be.